# How to assign a value to an imported global?

Tags: python, python-3.x

After all these years, I still don't grok globals in Python. My problem is showing up in a uWSGI app, where in `init()` I'm setting `BROWSER = webdriver.Firefox()` after declaring `global BROWSER`, and it's not actually setting the variable. But I'm also seeing it at the Python command line, and hopefully if I can understand why this simple example isn't working, it will solve my uWSGI issues as well.

`globaltest.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
'''
Test of keyword `global`
'''
GLOBALTEST = None

def init():
    global GLOBALTEST
    GLOBALTEST = 'Something'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('before init: GLOBALTEST', GLOBALTEST)
    init()
    print(' after init: GLOBALTEST', GLOBALTEST)
```

Execution:

```
jcomeau@bendergift:/tmp$ ./globaltest.py 
before init: GLOBALTEST None
 after init: GLOBALTEST Something
jcomeau@bendergift:/tmp$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from globaltest import *
>>> GLOBALTEST
>>> init()
>>> GLOBALTEST
>>>
```

Comment: that much I know... but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to remember is that Python has only one scope that is *truly* global: the built-in scope. The "global" scope is really a *module* global scope, and there is one for each module in the program.

There are *two* global variables named `GLOBALTEST` in your interactive session. One is part of the global scope of the module `globaltest`; the other is part of the global scope of your interactive session, the module `__main__`.

`init` sets the value of `globaltest.GLOBALTEST`, because Python uses lexical scoping. You are checking the value of `__main__.GLOBALTEST` before and after calling `init`.

If you check the value of `globaltest.GLOBALTEST`, you'll see *its* value change:

```
>>> from globaltest import *
>>> import globaltest
>>> globaltest.GLOBALTEST
>>> init()
>>> globaltest.GLOBALTEST
'Something'
>>> GLOBALTEST
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't figure out a way to translate that understanding into my uwsgi app, lacking an understanding of how uwsgi works. But you answered my question, so thank you.

Comment: Why can he reference `init()` without the `globaltest.` prefix?

Comment: Because it was imported by `from globaltest import *` (something I neglected to add to this example; will fix).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s answer, I was able to partially solve my uwsgi problem with the following kludge:

```
if not APP in sys.modules:  # will be the case with uwsgi
    exec('import %s' % APP)
sys.modules[APP].BROWSER = webdriver.Firefox()
```

However, the thread I'm running in the background still doesn't work correctly, as it did before I tried to move the webdriver initialization into a subroutine. So I'm back to initializing it in my `if __name__ == '__main__'` and `else` blocks.

Comment: Use `if APP not in sys.modules`; it generates the exact same code, but reads better.